Global dynamic variables in react native
I'm new to react native. I need to transfer a web game written on canvas to a mobile application.
I encountered the following problem: all variables in a web application are global, they can be used anywhere, but react native has different properties.
I'm building the layout of my application, using components, and functions to calculate physics in regular modules.
I need to get global variables that store the game state.
I found for the following 3 ways:

Using global:
I believe that creating global variables that store game state in
this way is not a good idea

Using useContext:
This hook allows you to have a global context, but you can only get
it inside components, and I use regular modules to calculate physics
and there is no way to access such variables

Using libraries:


I chose the zustand library and wrote the following logic:
My canvas component:
import Canvas from "react-native-canvas";
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useCanvasStore} from "@/store/canvasStore";

export default function TableCanvas() {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    const setCanvasRef = useCanvasStore(state => state.setCanvasRef);
    const setContext = useCanvasStore(state => state.setContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (canvasRef.current) {
            const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
        
            setCanvasRef(canvasRef);
            setContext(ctx);
        }
    }, [canvasRef]);

    return (
        <Canvas style={styles.tableCanvas} ref={canvasRef}/>
    );
}

canvasStore:
import { create } from 'zustand'

export const useCanvasStore = create(set => ({
    canvasRef: null,
    setCanvasRef: (value) => set({canvasRef: value}),
    context: null,
    setContext: (value) => set({context: value}),
}));

Some module in which the game physics will be calculated:
import {useCanvasStore} from "@/store/canvasStore";

const canvasRef = useCanvasStore.getState().canvasRef;
const context = useCanvasStore.getState().context;

At this stage, I encountered a problem: when updating a global variable, for example, through setContext(ctx), it is not updated in other files, that is, there I need to re-use useCanvasStore.getState()..., which, it seems to me, is again causes inconvenience or am I bothering in vain and can the variables really be re-received or is this normal? For some reason it seems to me that this will cause a load, even if the slightest
I want to know the easiest and most correct way to store global game state variables that will always be relevant in different places in the application.
